# Setting one column the records from another, just replacing spaces with commas

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So, our database has a column "meta_keywords" that is largely empty. I want to change this by making the meta_keywords the same results as the "title" column, except rather than spaces I want commas.

So if the title was "Virginia State Bank" the meta_keywords would be "virginia,state,bank"

However, this doesn't work:

`update my_table set meta_keywords = concat(title, ',', REPLACE(meta_keywords, ' ', ',') WHERE meta_keywords LIKE (' ')`;

I'm guessing I can't do a replace like that, however, if I simply set the meta_keywords the "title" column and run this:

```
UPDATE my_table SET meta_keywords= REPLACE(meta_keywords, ' ', ',') WHERE meta_keywords LIKE (' ');
```

Nothing happens (query runs, but no effected records) even though there are spaces in the mea_keywords table.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you test the query in `SELECT` ?

Comment: The latter query, I ran straight forwardly and nothing changed (no idea on that one as its a simple replace. The first one, Im not sure how I would run that as a select.

Comment: do `SELECT REPLACE(meta_keywords, ' ', ',') FROM my_table  WHERE meta_keywords LIKE (' ')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is using `LIKE (' ')`. You're doing it like `IN (' ')`. If you want to replace all spaces into comma, you can just skip defining `WHERE`. Just do:

```
UPDATE my_table SET meta_keywords = CONCAT(title, ',', REPLACE(meta_keywords, ' ', ','));
```

Also, it's a good practice to test your query first to see what & how will it update by doing a `SELECT` like following:

```
SELECT CONCAT(title, ',', REPLACE(meta_keywords, ' ', ',')) FROM my_table;
```

Comment: So, this sets the meta_keywords to the title column, but doesn't replace the spaces wtih commas. So "Virginia State Bank" in keywords ends up "Virigina State Bank,". However, I can run this to remove the spaces after the fact.

UPDATE my_table
SET meta_keywords = REPLACE(meta_keywords, ' ', ',')
WHERE meta_keywords LIKE ('% %');

So I guess it's fine even if not one query.

Comment: It does replace see this demo https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s6qLfXEgcRpNy7SsbUas2T/1

Comment: Strange, using MySQL 5.7 running on PHPMYADMIN,  0 rows affected. (Query took 1.5161 seconds.). I wonder whats happening on my end, very strange.

Comment: maybe the spaces in your meta_keywords column is not exactly spaces?

Comment: They are, because if I seperate the queries (set meta_keywords = title" and then REPLACE(meta_keywords, ' ', ',')
WHERE meta_keywords LIKE ('% %'); as a different query, I get the correct results just not combined. So, I honestly have no idea. You answered first, so Ill give you best answer even though it doesn't work for me strangely.

Comment: You should accept the answer that can work with your situation. Which I can see that @nbk answer is similar to your attempt `WHERE meta_keywords LIKE ('% %')` so you should accept that one :)

Comment: Weirdly enough, his ALSO changes 0 results despite being the exact same as what I do now basically, just it doesn't work combined. I really have no idea haha.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the PHPmyadmin ? Do you have any other tools you can test with? Something like SQLyog community?

Answer (score 1):

This shows how your query works, yourt prior Update would not find any rows matching

I added LOWER because your question put sall workds into lower case

> ```
> CREATE TABLE my_table  (
>   `title` varchar(10)
>   ,`meta_keywords` VARCHAR(50)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO my_table 
>   ( `title`,`meta_keywords`)
> VALUES
>   ( 'Apple','Virginia State Bank'),
>   ( 'Banana','Pensilvania State Bank'),
>   ( 'Pear','washington State BANK');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> update my_table 
>    set meta_keywords =  CONCAT(`title`,',',REPLACE(LOWER(`meta_keywords`),' ',',')) 
> WHERE meta_keywords LIKE ('% %');;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM my_table ;
> ```
>
> ```
> title  | meta_keywords                
> :----- | :----------------------------
> Apple  | Apple,virginia,state,bank    
> Banana | Banana,pensilvania,state,bank
> Pear   | Pear,washington,state,bank
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3ed22ae14c24f2ba6704eb408259f353)*